# Does a quadratic function that is bounded below have a global minimum?

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima

suppose that  $f(x)=x^TAx+2b^Tx+c$  and $A$ is positive semidefinite.
$A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix in $\Bbb R$, $b \in \Bbb R^n$ and $c\in \Bbb R$.

if $f$ is bounded below then does it have a global minimum?
I think it should be correct but I could not prove it. Can any one help?

Comment: What is $A$?  Where does $x$ live?  What are $b$ and $c$?  Can you remind us what is meant by "semidefinite"?  You think that $f$ should have a global minimum---why?  Please add this context to your question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I edited the post. semidefinite means $\forall x\in \Bbb R^n$ we have $x^TAx\ge 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of minimum should be the center of symmetry of this function. That is, find $m$ a point so that 
$$f(m+x) = f(m-x)$$ for all $x$. We calculate a bit 
$$(m+x)^TA(m+x) + 2b^T(m+x) - (m-x)^TA(m-x)-2b^T(m-x)=4 (m^TA+b^T)x$$

Assume that the equation $m^TA+b^T$ has a solution $m$. Then we have 
$$f(x) = (x-m)^TA(x-m) -m^T A m +c$$
(this is "completing the square").  Now this function is beounded below if and only if $A$ is positive semidefinite -- in that case $m$ will be a point of minimum.

Assume that the equation (in $m$)  $m^TA+b^T$ has no solution. Then $b$ is not in the image of $A$. Recall that for symmetric matrices $A$ we have 
$$Im A=(\ker A)^{\perp}$$
Therefore, $b$ is not perpendicular to $\ker A$. Take $x_0$ in $\ker A$, $b^Tx_0\ne 0$. Then we have 
$$f(\alpha x_0) = b^T x_0\cdot \alpha  + c$$ so $f$ restricted to $\mathbb{R}x_0$ is not bounded.

Comment: Why do you know that $A$ is symmetric?

Comment: we can always use $\frac{A^T +A}{2}$ instead. But I think he assumes symmetric to start with

Comment: I'm sorry, could you briefly tell why we can symmetrize? I do not see it. If we can assume $A$ to be symmetric, can't we just diagonalize and immediately get the statement?

Comment: @Severin Schraven: $A$ and $A^T$ give the same function,  so we can average. Yes, we can diagonalize (if' $A$ symmetric) and get the statement right away.

Comment: Could you please tell that if $A$ symmetric how can we get the statement immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any conic section which is bounded below has a global minimum.

Since it is bounded below it has an infimum which is attained due to continuity.

Comment: It appears that the OP is not talking about conic sections, but higher dimensional analogs.  It is not at all obvious to me that your answer addresses that question.